# Copy Request Object in Edge as Response Payload

Tags: apigee

I would like to copy the request object (headers,params,body) as payload of response and send it back. Is there good way or suggested way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using the `AssignMessage` policy to copy the request object and assign it to the response object.  Example policy:

```
<AssignMessage name="CopyRequestToResponse">
    <AssignTo type="response" createNew="false">response</AssignTo>
    <Copy source="request"/>
</AssignMessage>
```

This policy should execute in a `TargetEndpoint` response flow as the scope of `response` is Target Response.  You can find the Apigee documentation for the policy and variable scopes here:

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/generate-or-modify-messages-using-assignmessage
http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/variables-reference

Comment: Very clever solution. One up for you.